# Creating Group-Level in Dynamic Report (MS Access)

Tags: ms-access

I need to create a dynamic (on the fly) report, because the number and names of fields will change frequently. I have it all worked out except I cannot figure out how to create a group header based upon a field name.

Here was my first try, which returns "The number you used to refer to the form or report section is invalid."

```
Dim rpt as Report
dim txtNew as Access.Textbox

set rpt = CreateReport

With rpt
.Width = 8500
.RecordSource = "IS_Subscales_GB_Final"
End With

Set txtNew = CreateReportControl(rpt.Name, acTextBox, acGroupLevel1Header, , "FriendlyName01", 0, 0)
txtNew.FontBold = True
txtNew.FontSize = 16
txtNew.SizeToFit

DoCmd.OpenReport rpt.Name, acViewPreview
```

So I next tried to use CreateGroupLevel, but this returns the error "You can't call this function when the Group, Sort, and Total Pane is open."

```
Dim rpt as Report
dim txtnew as Access.Textbox
Dim vargrplvl As Variant

set rpt = CreateReport

With rpt
.Width = 8500
.RecordSource = "IS_Subscales_GB_Final"
End With

vargrplvl = CreateGroupLevel(rpt.Name, "FriendlyName", True, False)
rpt.Section(acGroupLevel1Header).Height = 400    

Set txtNew = CreateReportControl(rpt.Name, acTextBox, acGroupLevel1Header, , "FriendlyName01", 0, 0)
txtNew.FontBold = True
txtNew.FontSize = 16
txtNew.SizeToFit

DoCmd.OpenReport rpt.Name, acViewPreview
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Code shows `With rpt` twice and should not compile. Is this just a typo in the question?

Comment: Fixed the OP to remove the duplicated With rpt lines which were included accidentally

Comment: So far, only thing I can find suggests creating and saving a blank report and then programmatically manipulating that report object in design view.

Answer (score 1):

I made multiple mistakes but also, Access has a quirk where it unexpectedly throws the 2451 error ("You can't call this function when the Group, Sort, and Total Pane is open.")---this happens only if the last time you were in Design view for a report, you had the Group, Sort, and Total Pane open. Access saves that setting so you either need to go back into a report in Design view and turn the panel off, or use an error handler to work around it. So here is a learning lesson coming from the whole ordeal:

```
Dim rpt as Report
Dim vargrplevel As Variant 'holds grouping level of report
Dim txtNew as Access.Textbox ' textbox control
Dim lblNew As Access.Label ' label control

set rpt = CreateReport   'creates a report object
with rpt
.width = 8500 'sets width of report
.RecordSource = "IS_Subscales_GB_Final" ' your table or query
end with

'start setting your controls on the report using CreateReportControl, i.e.:

Set lblNew = CreateReportControl(rpt.Name, acLabel, acDetail, , , 2700, 0, 270, 315)
lblNew.Caption = "O"
lblNew.FontSize = 12
lblNew.FontBold = True

'To add a group level to the report, it MUST be in acViewDesign!
DoCmd.OpenReport rpt.Name, acViewDesign 

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler 
'if the Group, Sort, and Total pane was left "on" then this next line will throw error 2451
vargrplevel = CreateGroupLevel(rpt.Name, "FriendlyName01", True, False) 'Creates a group header, named "FriendlyName01"
rpt.Section(acGroupLevel1Header).Height = 400 'optional; sets the header height

Set txtNew = CreateReportControl(rpt.Name, acTextBox, acGroupLevel1Header, , "FriendlyName01", 0, 0) 'This actually inserts the field into the header as textbox control
txtNew.FontBold = True
txtNew.FontSize = 16
DoCmd.Save acReport, rpt.Name

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
If Err.Number = 2154 Then
    RunCommand acCmdSortingAndGrouping 'turns off the Sorting and Grouping pane
    Resume
Else
    Debug.Print "Error in creating report header (EH01- " & Err.Number & ")"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Cheers.

Comment: I was beginning to wonder if needed an error handler. Glad you got it figured out. Ran the code, nice start.